# Calculation sum with different date range Qlik / MySql

Tags: mysql, date, sum, qliksense

I’m work in Qlik Sense and I don’t know how can in resolve my problem in load script or with SQL request.

I have a table in which I want to calculate stock quantity when movement type = Perremption.

| PN | SN | Stock_date | Stock_qty | stock_qty_reference | stock_type_mouvement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3694 | 3694AC | 30/09/2022 | 1 |  | VP |
| 3694 | 3694AC | 02/02/2023 | 1 |  | VP |
| 3694 | 3694AC | 28/02/2022 | 1 |  | VP |
| 3694 | 3694AC | 30/05/2024 |  | 5 | Perremption |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 05/10/2022 | 1 |  | VP |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 05/05/2023 | 1 |  | VP |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 06/07/2023 | 1 |  | VP |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 01/01/2024 |  | 3 | Perremption |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 11/11/2024 |  |  |  |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 10/10/2022 | 1 |  | VP |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 11/07/2023 | 1 |  | VP |
| 1234 | 1234BB | 01/05/2024 |  | 2 | Perremption |

Example for Pn 7895 with a reference stock = 3, you must sum all the stock quantities which are less than or equal to 02/28/2023 - the sum of all the reference stocks which are less than or equal to 02/28/2023 .

So the calculation is as follows sum (1+1+1) - sum (3) = 0

For PN 7895 with a reference stock = 2, the sum of the quantity of stock between 02/28/2023 and 12/31/2023 must be calculated - the sum of the reference stock between 02/28/2023 and 31/12/2023.

How can I calculate this with request SQL or in loaf script Qlik Sense ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is your expected result for the given data and what is `01/01/10/2024`?

Comment: Hi @KenWhite i edit my post and i delete the picture and i did a table

Comment: Hi @FanoFN,  Thanks you for your reply. 01/01/2024 it's date of perremption which have a stock_reference =3.

Comment: @FanoFN |For example for the PN 3694 with a stock reference = 5, I must fill in the column stock_quantite which is empty, it is
 to say the one where I have an expiry date which is equal to 05/30/2024.

So I have to do the following calculation:
SUM of all VP that are less than or equal to 05/30/2024 - SUM of all Perremption that are less than or equal to 05/30/2024

Comment: @FanoFN, For example for the PN 1234 with a stock reference = 3, I have to fill in the column stock_quantite which is empty, it is
 to say the one where I have an expiry date which is equal to 01/01/2024.

So I have to do the following calculation:
The sum of all VP which are <=05/30/2024 - sum of all Perremption which are between <=05/30/2024. I know i can do a sum with group by PN and Stock_reference, i think

Comment: @FanoFN For example for the PN 3694 with a stock reference = 2, I have to fill in the column stock_quantite which is empty, it is
 to say the one where I have an expiry date which is equal to 01/05/2024.

So I have to do the following calculation:
The sum of all VP which are between 01/01/2024 and 05/01/2024 - sum of all Perremption which are between 01/01/2024 and 05/01/2024

Comment: Actually, I'm asking you to post into your question how the result should look like at the end. Will it still look like the table with all the columns? or how?